# using Spring DI with Quarkus, the native image doesn't expose the Spring Rest points

Tags: java, spring, docker, quarkus

I'm trying to use Quarkus to run a small application. I'm using Spring DI and Spring Rest points to implement the application. I'm building everything using Gradle.

When I run the application locally using the quarkusDev task, the application works as expected and if I build a Docker image using a JVM to run, it also works.
But, when I try to build a native image, using this guide https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image (using a multistage image to build), the image is being built, but no Spring bean is being recognized.

Is there anything I'm not doing?

Comment: Could you share some simple project on which you observe the behavior?

Comment: All I can share is also in this bug report. https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6868

Comment: Added this repo
https://github.com/AnakinPt/quarkus-spring